# How to combine several lists into one list in MS Excel 2016?

Tags: excel

I have 3 table and I want to add them together so that I have a single, unified, table of Value and Count.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is you create a fourth table with value and count,copy and paste the data under another, use "remove duplicate" on "Data" main tab and insert a SUMIF function like on the image >>>.

[image]